# How to extract all dependency files out of package instead of installing them

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, aws

I need to extract dependency files for `libdbus-glib-1-2` and `libxt6` package because I need to ship these dependencies to AWS Lambda so I have to manually add these dependencies to my code.

I have tried [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-linux-binary-package/) that is for Amazon Linux AMI. Is there any similar tool like `yumdownloader` and `rpmdev-extract` for ubuntu machine that can help me to extract all `.so` files?

or is there any alternative way?

Thanks

Comment: You can see the dependencies of a packages via ```apt show package | grep Depends``` and using [apt-file](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/apt-file.htm) you can search through all the packages (even if they aren't installed yet) to see what's inside and also you can see all the ```.so``` files.I don't know if these are exactly the same as ```yumdownloader``` because I haven't used it before but feel free to ask if there are also other requirements.

Comment: And also if you prefer using the web interface , you can explore package dependencies [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/).